How to debug CSS design issues persisting **only** on production?
I Have a Node.js based url shortening GitHub project deployed on vercel and Its been a while I've been facing a discrepancy in the CSS design e.g: HTML table and body elements on the Pixel 7 device using Brave browser. 
The iPhone and other android devices running Safari, Brave and Chrome work as expected
I cleared the browser's cache and site data but to no avail. 
Everything was in-place and fine when I ran the project locally from my ip and port on the Pixel 7.
package.json
What am i missing?

What i was missing was disabling cookies on the browser and retrying. It worked
